# Can I wire a exterior light to a inside outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a defiant led motion light and I'm mounting it above the garage and the garage has been converted to a room, So behind the garage door is a wall with 2 standard outlets the top outlet usually has a window ac unit plugged in (but I unplug it when I'm not using it) and the bottom outlet is used for when I plug my keyboard in or laptop charger ETC, so it's usually free most of the time.

So I'm just wanting to make sure I can wire my motion light to one of these outlets with no problems or overloading of too much power.

Sorry if I sound like an amateur this will be my first time wiring anything on my own and first DIY

the exterior light model is this dfi 5988-wh, and the specs are 2450 lumens output and the watt equivalence is 29.23 that's all I has on the box.

Any help, thoughts or suggestions would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: A/C is a heavy load of 1/3 to 2/3 of circuit capacity.  Laptop charging is maybe 1/20 of circuit capacity,  Phones and LED security lights are negligible load.

Answer (score 1):

The AC won't be running at night when the LED light is needed . LED lights draw very little power so you will probably be fine. The high bay LED's I have recently installed with similar lumens draw only .5 amps.